# Problem relating $p$-defect zero characters with their values on a field of characteristic $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters, algebraic-integers

Studying Gabriel Navarro's book "Character Theory and the McKay Conjecture", I've come across the following problem. First, let's fix some notation: $G$ will be a finite group, $R$ will denote the algebraic integers of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $p$ will be a prime, $M$ will be a maximal ideal of $R$ containing $pR$ and $\mathbb{F}$ will denote the field $R/M$, where $*:R \to \mathbb{F}$ is the canonical projection.

> Let $\chi\in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ and write $\chi^*$ for the function $\chi^*(g) = \chi(g)^*$. Then:
>
> 1. If $\chi_1, ..., \chi_t \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ are all distinct and of $p$-defect zero, then $\chi_1^*, ..., \chi_t^*$ are $\mathbb{F}$-linearly independent;
> 2. If $\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G)$ has $p$-defect zero and $x \in G$ is such that $\chi(x)^* \neq 0$, then $|G|_p = |x^G|_p$ (i.e., the greatest power of $p$ that divides the order of $G$ also divides the size of the conjugacy class of $x$);
> 3. The number of irreducible $p$-defect zero characters of $G$ is bounded above by the number of conjugacy classes $K$ of $G$ such that $|K|_p = |G|_p$;

---

---

**My attempt**

---

**1.** Suppose $\sum_i \lambda_i \chi_i^* = 0$. Then we may take $\mu_i \in R$ such that $\mu_i^* = \lambda_i$. Our goal is $\mu_i \in M$. Take $\theta = \sum_i \mu_i \chi_i$. Our hypothesis guarantees that $\theta(G) \subset M$. We will use **2.** and its notation. We have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^t \lambda_i \chi_i(1)_{p'}^* \lambda_{\chi_i}(
\hat{K}) = \sum_{i=1}^t \lambda_i \chi_i(1)_{p'}^* \left( \frac{|K|\chi_i(x_K)}{\chi_i(1)} \right)^* = \sum_{i=1}^t \left( \frac{|K|\mu_i \chi_i(x_K)}{p^a} \right)^* = \left( \frac{|K|\theta(x_K)}{p^a} \right)^*$$
where $x_K$ is a representative of the conjugacy class $K$ and $p^a$ is the $p$-part of $|G|$.

Now, either $\chi_i(x_K)^* = 0$ for all $i$, or there exists some $i$ such that $\chi_i(x_K)^* \neq 0$. In this last case, by **2.**, the expression above will yield $0$. All that's left is to show the same for the first case from which it will follow, from the linear independence of the $\lambda_{\chi_i}$ (which can be shown for characters of $p$-defect zero), that $\lambda_i = 0$ for all $i$.

---

**2.** Let $\lambda_\chi : Z(\mathbb{F}G) \to \mathbb{F}$ be the algebra homomorphism defined by $\lambda_\chi(\hat{K}) = \left( \frac{|K|\chi(x)}{\chi(1)}\right)^*$, where $K$ is a conjugacy class of $G$ with representative $x$ (that this is well-defined and is a homomorphism was done previously in the book). We can write:
$$\left( \frac{|K|\chi(x)}{\chi(1)}\right)^* = \left( \frac{|K|_p |K|_{p'}\chi(x)}{\chi(1)_p \chi(1)_{p'}}\right)^* \in \mathbb{F}$$

i.e., separating out the power of $p$ of the two integers from the rest. Now, by hypothesis, $\left( \frac{\chi(1)_{p'}}{|K|_{p'}\chi(x)}\right)^*$ is a well-defined element of $\mathbb{F}$. Thus:
$$\left( \frac{|K|_p |K|_{p'}\chi(x)}{\chi(1)_p \chi(1)_{p'}}\right)^* \cdot \left( \frac{\chi(1)_{p'}}{|K|_{p'}\chi(x)}\right)^* = \left( \frac{|K|_p}{ \chi(1)_p}\right)^* \in \mathbb{F}$$

This then proves $|K|_p \geq \chi(1)_p$. As the latter is equal to $|G|_p$, we get $|K|_p = |G|_p$, as desired.

---

**3.** Here, my guess would be, using **2.**, to find an element $x$ of $G$ such that $\chi(x)^* \neq 0$ for one defect zero caracter $\chi$, but not any other. This, I have no idea how to do. It will probably involve **1.** somehow, but I can't see it...

---

Could anyone please provide some hint on how to finish item **1.** and how to approach **3.**? Is my intuition for this last item correct and, if so, how to go about applying it?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I would hazard a guess that this is a particular version of some much more general result for modular characters, but I don't know much of the latter...

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun What is the MSE policy on a question referring to a single exercise with multiple items? I could break it into two, but they would intersect a lot…